# Manipulate Javascript objects from java

Tags: java, javascript

I have completed a program to  manipulate JavaScript objects from Java

```
String buildInfoJS = "var build_info = new Object;build_info.BUILD_DISPLAY_VERSION       = 'Build 201302232300'";
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine jsEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
jsEngine.eval(buildInfoJS);
Object object = jsEngine.get("build_info");
System.out.println(object.getClass().getName());

if (object instanceof NativeObject  ) {
    NativeObject nObj = (NativeObject)object 
    for (Object key: nObj.getAllIds()) {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```

Now object is `instanceof sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeObject`, but I can't use these directly.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Have you got any parse error, or any error?

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "I can't use there directly". What do you want to do with the object ? What have you tried and what error did you get ?

Comment: What is the purpose of parsing the javascript object and converting it into Java object? Can you not serialize the javascript object using the JSON serializer and deserialize it back to Java object?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use JSON and the Java JSON API? Alternatively you could also use GWT (Google Web Toolkit).

Answer (score 0):

Consider coercion to Java types via the scripting engine.

For example, this code coerces the property names to native Java:

```
  public static void main(String[] a) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager()
        .getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    Object o = engine.eval("(function(){return {foo:'Hello', bar:100};}());");
    engine.put("toInspect", o);
    engine.put("visitor", new PropertyNameVisitor());
    engine.eval("(function(obj){" +
        " var arr, prop;" +
        " arr = [];" +
        " for(prop in obj) {" +
        "  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {" +
        "   visitor.visit(prop);" +
        "  }" +
        " }" +
        " return arr;" +
        "}(toInspect));");
  }

  public static class PropertyNameVisitor {
    public void visit(String name) {
      System.out.println(name);
    }
  }
```